# Linux Fedora 20: how can I find out what is happening behind the scenes

Tags: scheduling

I have Fedora 20 installed, using MATE desktop and zshell and something weird is going on.

I get lots of odd unexplained beeps from my speakers, even though the volume is turned down to zero, so something is going on in the background; and last night, at 0200, after I had `shutdown` earlier at about 2300, I found that the LED on my one Terabyte USB hard drive was on. I did not touch anything and it went off soon after I noticed it.

I have searched the Internet for a solution, but I can't understand the arcane acronyms and details of most of the information. I would like to understand what is going on, but I don't know where to look. I believe that the shutdown machine would be in run-level 1, with some things running, but investigating that also leads me into deep, unfathomable waters.

I have looked in crontab crond and corosync, and anything else that looks likely, with nothing looking suspicious, and really, no clue about what I should expect.

`crontab -e` showed this, left over from my experiments a while ago with scheduling (I added `#` to make the line a comment, just now, to stop it):

```
* * * * * /testrsync/zenitytest.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I also note, with embarrassment, that `/test..` is not in my home directory.

I forgot to mention, in my first posting of this question, that once a day in the late afternoon or evening, the computer suddenly, without warning, shuts down and reboots to my normal login screen, but without losing anything I was doing. It seems to happen as I open a new tab in Maxthon web browser, but I am not sure of this as it takes me by surprise every time.

This is all a paean to ignorance, so my question is: please how can I find out what is going on?

Comment: The power is off in this "shutdown" machine? Perhaps the system is hanging during the shutdown process and processes are still running?

Comment: Thanks sim. The power is not completely off, since the light in the USB mouse continues to glow, although that may simply mean that the PSU is powered up ready for switch on again.

Comment: @HarryWeston I have thought about what to do, if I have some problems with my systems where I come to a dead end investigating it my self. Then I would probably hire some expert for the job.